# Unique values from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I need to make statistics of data which is fetched from an HTML table.
The first column is gatewayId, the second one is statusId and the third one gsmError.
I successfully filtered that table and pushed those values into an array.

Now I need to make a list of unique gateways from that array.
I do not know which values are gonna be in that array, I just know that they are contained in column "10".

The array looks like this:
[ "2951", "3", "511", "2737", "3", "502", "2737", "3", "502", "2732"...]

```
let messageLogTable = $("#tableId");
    var filteredColData = [];

    messageLogTable.find('tr').each(function(rowIndex, rowData) {
        if(rowIndex > 0){

            $(this).find('td').each(function(colIndex, colData) {

                if(colIndex === 10 || colIndex === 11 || colIndex === 17) {
                    filteredColData.push($.trim(colData.textContent));
                }
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(filteredColData);
```

The result should be like this:
2951, 2737, 2732

I would like that this is done using jQuery, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: 2737 appears twice

Comment: It might be prudent to keep an array of `object`s with the `gatewayId`,`statusId`, and `gsmError` properties. From there you can filter it down. At least that would be easier than just keeping an array of seemingly non-descriptive values.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I thought of the same, just was not sure how to store those values into an object.

Comment: @Orpheus, if you could provide me the code for pushing those values into an object, that would be great.
Like so:

var gatewayList = {
      gatewayId: 123,
      statusId: 12,
      gsmError: 502
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this job as follows;

```js
var  data = ["2951", "3", "511", "2737", "3", "502", "2737", "3", "502", "2732"],
gatewayID = [...new Set(data.reduce((p,c,i) => !(i%3) ? p.concat(c) : p, []))]
console.log(gatewayID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of discovered and use a filter.

```js
var messageLogTable = $("#tableId");
var filteredColData = [];
var discovered = [];
messageLogTable.find('tr').each(function(rowIndex, rowData) {
    $(this).find('td').each(function(colIndex, colData) {
        if (filteredColData.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < filteredColData.length; i++) {
                if (filteredColData[i] == $(this).html()) {
                    discovered.push(filteredColData[i]);
                }
            };
        };
        filteredColData.push($(this).html());
    });
});
filteredColData = filteredColData.filter(function(x) {
    return discovered.indexOf(x) < 0
})
alert(JSON.stringify(filteredColData));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableId">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```